# cell.imageview.image not showing image on table

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I am getting image URL from firebase but when trying to show on table i am not able to see one.Code is below.I am saving images in firebase from

> UIImagePickerController()

```
 public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allUsers", for: indexPath) as! allUserCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = allUserData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = allUserData[indexPath.row].email

        if let image = allUserData[indexPath.row].image  {
        let url = NSURL(string: image)
        let request = URLRequest(url:url! as URL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    print(image)
                    cell.imageView?.image = image
                }
            }

        }).resume()

    }
        return cell
}
}
```

The print(image) line gives me following-:

```
UIImage: 0x60800009b3f0>, {746, 498}
```

custom Cell Class.

```
class allUserCell:UITableViewCell{
    override init(style:UITableViewCellStyle,reuseIdentifier:String?) {
        super.init(style:.subtitle,reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: try printing `cell.imageView` and see if you get `nil`

Comment: @Aaron you mean cell.imageView.image ?

Comment: You're using a custom `UITableViewCell` not a `default` style `UITableViewCell` so you need to manually add a `UIImageView` to the cell's `contentView` preferably.

Comment: @Aaron don't think so but i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

add an extension

```
extension UIImageView{

    func setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl url: String){

        if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

then use 
`cell.imageView.setImageFromURl((stringImageUrl: imgURL))` // provide your Image url in the parameter as String

hope this will help you . All the best

Comment: it gives me error if i use if let url = NSURL(string: url).

Comment: which version of swift you are using